# Swift Decode a data type with many different formats

Tags: ios, codable, decodable, swift4.2

I am being returned a boolean in "several" different formats from a server (for the same structure and field).. I know it's ridiculous but I need to find a way to cleanly handle it.

So to de-serialize it, I do something like (sample program):

```
import Foundation

struct Foo: Codable {
    var isOpen: Bool?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        isOpen = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isOpen)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isOpen
    }
}

//He sends any one of these..
let json1 = "{ \"isOpen\": \"true\" }"
let json2 = "{ \"isOpen\": \"false\" }"
let json3 = "{ \"isOpen\": true }"
let json4 = "{ \"isOpen\": false }"
let json5 = "{ \"isOpen\": null }"
let json6 = "{ \"isOpen\": \"null\" }"
let json7 = "{ \"isOpen\": \"<null>\" }"

//He doesn't send this one.. but I wouldn't be surprised if I got it so I added it for fun (serializing the below `json8` and `json9` is not required for an answer).. :)

let json8 = "{ \"isOpen\": 0 }"
let json9 = "{ \"isOpen\": 1 }"

let json = [json1, json2, json3, json4, json5, json6, json7, json8, json9]
for js in json {
    if let rawData = js.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            let foo = try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: rawData)
            if let isOpen = foo.isOpen {
                print("\(isOpen)\n\n")
            } else {
                print("State Unknown\n\n")
            }
        } catch {
            print("\(error)\n\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I use Swift Codable (which all our data structures already use), then we will get a type-mismatch and the error/exception is thrown. I have thought about try-catching every case and trying another decode with a different type but then it'll end up like:

```
do {
    isOpen = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isOpen)
}
catch {
    do {
        isOpen = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .isOpen) != 0
    }
    catch {
        do {
            isOpen = Bool(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .isOpen))
        }
        catch {
            do {
                isOpen = try container.decodeIfPreset(Bool.self, forKey: .isOpen)  ?? GiveUpAndAssignDefaultValueHere..
            }
            catch {
                isOpen = nil //no idea..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then that got me thinking about converting it to string first then trying to parse that instead so I ended up with (which is nicer than the above at least):

```
do {
    isOpen = try container.decode(Bool?.self, forKey: .isOpen)
}
catch {
    do {
        isOpen = Bool(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .isOpen))
    }
    catch {
        isOpen = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .isOpen) != 0
    }
}
```

but surely there's a better way? Any ideas???

Comment: you want  to use the final value always as Bool ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than `catch`ing the errors I'd conditional bind the types

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    var isOpen: Bool?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let boolOpen = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isOpen) {
            isOpen = boolOpen
        } else if let intOpen = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .isOpen) {
            isOpen = intOpen == 1
        } else if let stringOpen = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .isOpen) {
            switch stringOpen {
            case "true", "1": isOpen = true
            case "false", "0": isOpen = false
            default : isOpen = nil
            }
        } else {
            isOpen = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A new suggestion is to Decode multiValues  using the same CodingKey `isOpen`

the code would be something like this,

```
struct Foo: Codable {
var isOpen: Bool?
private var isOpenInty: Int?
private var isOpenStringy: String?
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    do {
        isOpen = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isOpen)

    }catch {
        do {
            isOpenInty = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .isOpen)
            if isOpenInty == 0  {isOpen = true} else {isOpen = false}
        }catch {
            isOpenStringy = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .isOpen)
            if isOpenStringy == "true" {isOpen = true} else {isOpen = false}
        }
    }
}
```

And based on any of those value, set `isOpen`  value.

Just a different way of handling this case.

pretty much the same idea of yours here,

```
   do {
        isOpen = try container.decode(Bool?.self, forKey: .isOpen)
    }
    catch {
        do {
            isOpen = Bool(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .isOpen))
        }
        catch {
            isOpen = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .isOpen) != 0
        }
    }
```

but your code gives `State Unknown` in case of null, the code above it simply handle it if null, as false

Comment: pretty much your code and this one,  is the cleanest way to handle this case so far.  if you had a better way, regard this answer please post it, as i would like to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Another method, same principle, just for fun. It's very O.K.

```
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
_  =  [ try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isOpen),
    try?  container.decode(String.self, forKey: .isOpen),
    try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .isOpen)].first{
switch $0 {
case is Bool:
    self.isOpen  = $0 as? Bool
    return true
case is Int:
    self.isOpen  = ($0 as! Int) == 0 ? false : (($0 as! Int) == 1 ? true : nil)
    return true
case is String:
    self.isOpen  = Bool.init($0 as! String)
    return true
default:
    return false
}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the need for force casting by using syntax like: `case b as Bool`